# get_FOO_display returning empty string

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a very simple choices field in my model:

```
MY_TYPES = (
    (1, _("Type 1")),
    (2, _("Type 2")),
    (3, _("Type 3"))
)
my_field = models.IntegerField(choices=MY_TYPES, default=1)
```

`_` is imported as `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

I'm getting the correct result when I `manage.py shell_plus`. Example:

```
m = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
m.get_my_field_display() # returns the value correctly
```

However, it's returning an empty string in my template: `{{ m.get_my_field_display }}`

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using `values_list()` from my view: `MyModel.objects.values_list('my_field', 'others')`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `m` have valid value for `my_field`?

Comment: What does `{{ m.my_field }}` display in the template? By using made up variable names, you could be hiding the problem.

Comment: `m.my_field` returns the correct Integer value. I just noticed that I'm using values_list() might be the issue. I will update my question.

Comment: Use `MyModel.objects.only('my_field', 'others')`.

Comment: @AlexMorozov could you please post as an answer to I can accept it? I believe this is helpful for anyone having the same issue, I didn't know of `only`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use model's methods your queryset should return models, not plain values. I suggest you changing your query to:

```
MyModel.objects.only('my_field', 'others')
```

So that you both select only the fields you need from the database and is still able to use model's methods. [More on `only` in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#only).

Answer (score 1):

The point of `values_list` is that, as the name implies, it returns a list of values, not model instances. So you can't use any model methods.

Unless you have a very good reason, you should always pass the actual models to your template; it allows you to store as much logic as you need in the model classes, and call those methods directly from the template.

Comment: thanks for the reply Daniel. I'm using values_list because the model has a lot of fields and I only need around 8 of them for this view. I'll see what I can do using values_list or something like that.

Comment: As Alex suggests, you can use `only`, which returns an actual model object but doesn't populate all the fields.